# Can not port forward devices connected using wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have been trying to get a Linux VPS server set up on my phone using LinuxDeploy. So far i have everything I need set up, but i need to have the ability to port forward certain ports (80, 443, 22) for the VPS to be useful, but for some reason I cannot port forward to devices connected by WIFI.

I tried port forwarding port 8000 to my PC connected by Ethernet cable, and sure enough it worked. I could access port 8000 from the web. Then I tried port forwarding to my MacBook Pro connected to the same network, but with WIFI, and it didn't work.

In my router, when I view the list of devices on the network, devices connected wirelessly are not showing up.

Here is an image of the devices seen by my router: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxQXA.png

As you can see, only two devices show up. The DESKTOP is my ethernet connected device, the other one is some device also connected by ethernet.

How can i port forward to devices that are not shown on this list? My DESKTOP Has IP of 192.168.1.x, my WIFI devices have IPs like 192.168.2.x.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: since your wifi is on another subnet, I have to assume you have a wifi router rather than an AP.  that implies you have a double-nat scenario. can you tell us a bit more about your network hardware, how its connected and how its configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution thanks to @Frank Thomas suggestion. I had two router login interfaces, one to configure my Ethernet network, the other to configure the wireless one.

Running `arp -a` gave my wifi routers IP. Also uPnP forwarding using miniupnpc for instance using `upnpc -a 192.168.2.x 8080 TCP` Forwarded to a local IP instead of an external IP, which was a dead giveaway that I needed to forward to the other router.

The solution ended up being simple: I used my Ethernet router to port forward to my wifi router. And my wifi router to route to my device.

Comment: If you want, you could make your Wi-Fi router an access point only, so you have a single network. It would make stuff like this unnecessary.